# LIMIT and Group By? How do I return the lowest 100 earning customers by country? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Hi I’ve a table database1

3 columns : customer_id , income , country

```
Customer_id
1001
1002
...

Income
5000
6000
7000

Country
SG
HK
VN
...
```

How do I write a query that returns the lowest 100 earning customers per country?

Is it possible to return:

```
Customer ID | country code
1003          SG
1004          SG
... 
1007          VN
...
```

So on

Thanks!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Btw, database1 is a very poor table name. I'd consider renaming it to customers.

Comment: Hi I’m using MySQL 8.0.16. Thanks.

Comment: Oh haha ok the table name was given to me as an assessment but I’ll keep that in mind in my own work next time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On mySQL 8 you can leverage a window function for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 
  country,
  customer_id,
  row_number() over(partition by country order by income asc) earn_rank
 FROM table
)x
WHERE x.earn_rank <= 100
```

You can conceive that this window function will sort the rows by country then by income, then start counting up from 1. Each time the country changes the row numbering starts over from 1 again. This means that for every country there will be a row numbered 1 (with the lowest income), and a 2, 3 etc. If we then wrap it up in another outer query that selects only rows where the number is less than 101 we get 100 rows per country